# Is it possible to do a double substitution with a shell string?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, programming, regex

Single Substitution is easy:

```
string="Mark Shuttleworth"
echo ${string/a/o}

Mork Shuttleworth
```

is it possible though to do a double at the same time?

```
echo ${string/a/o string/t/g} #doesn't work, but you get the idea

Mork Shuggleworgh
```

Regular Expressions suffice as an answer, if it is possible using them.

Thanks

Comment: Not an exact answer, but I couldn't get it to work, best I came up with... `echo $string | sed 's/a/o/g; s/t/g/g'`

Comment: @bc2946088 Hmmm, works, will see if it solves my particular issue.

Comment: @bc2946088 the string I need to do this on needs to be `eval`uated, so how am I going to pipe it in? Can you `eval` an `echo` `stdout`?

Comment: something like `eval "(echo $string | sed 's/a/o/g; s/t/g/g')"`?  -- Sorry, above my pay grade, I'd need more information that I could test.

Comment: @bc2946088 Yeah I deleted my comment when I realized that. Unfortunately the replacement I am trying to do is on single quotations, making this doubly more complicated

Comment: Can you escape them? I know it makes it ugly.  Hopefully someone chimes in with a clean, linear answer. :)

Comment: @bc2946088  `eval "(echo $woostring | sed \"s/'/'\\\''/g; s/∪/'/g\")"
`

Comment: @bc2946088 Your solution ended up working for me, put it down and I'll accept. What I ended up doing was dumping the string to a file, and running it.

Comment: The *right* way to do it in `sed` IMHO is to use the `y` (transliterate) command, not the `s` (substitute) command e.g. `sed 'y/at/og/' <<< "$string"`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I know, the only way to do it in current versions of `bash` is in two steps e.g.

```
$ string="Mark Shuttleworth"
$ string="${string//a/o}"; echo "${string//t/g}"
Mork Shuggleworgh
```

Attempts to nest substitutions result in an error:

```
$ echo "${${string//a/o}//t/g}"
bash: ${${string//a/o}//t/g}: bad substitution
```

Note that other shells may support such nested substitutions e.g. in `zsh 5.2`:

```
~ % string="Mark Shuttleworth"
~ % echo "${${string//a/o}//t/g}"
Mork Shuggleworgh
```

Of course, external tools such as `tr`, `sed`, `perl` can do it easily

```
$ sed 'y/at/og/' <<< "$string"
Mork Shuggleworgh

$ perl -pe 'tr /at/og/' <<< "$string"
Mork Shuggleworgh

$ tr at og <<< "$string"
Mork Shuggleworgh
```

Comment: I think this answer deserves it. I ended up piping `echo` to `sed` to which I `>` into a file. Because in my project, I was trying to do replace single quotes in a variable that could contain double quotes, I could not concatenate single quoted strings in a variable without it collapsing in on itself, losing the concatenation I needed to sanitize my string... if that makes any sense. Its been 15 hours I have been trying to solve this issue... Think its time for a nap.

Answer (score 6):

You're substituting single letters, so just use [`tr`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/tr.1.html):

```
tr at og
```

This causes each `a` to be replaced by `o` and each `t` to be replaced by `g`. With your example:

```
ek@Io:~$ tr at og <<<'Mark Shuttleworth'
Mork Shuggleworgh
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
echo ${string/a/o} ${string/t/g}
```

I'm using my tablet, no `bash` to test.

You may want to checkout using the `printf` command much more flexible.

Comment: That would display it twice...

Comment: `Mork Shuttleworth Mark Shugtleworth`